# twitter typeahead.js + bootstrap tagsinput = Object [object Object] has no method 'setQuery'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm using Twitter typeahead with Bootstrap Tags Input. The code looks like this:

```
$(selector).tagsinput('input').typeahead({
    name:'tags',
    remote: "/admin/tags/search/%QUERY?format=json"
}).bind('typeahead:selected', function (object, datum) {
    $(selector).tagsinput('add', datum);
    $(selector).tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', 'test');
});
```

This is pretty much copied from the example here: http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/
(to see the original example you need to click 'Show code' in the Typeahead section.

It works apart from the line `$(selector).tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', '');` which gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setQuery'
```

That line is supposed to reset the text that has already been entered to typeahead control after the suggestion has been added to the list of tags. If I add the same line outside of the even callback like this:

```
$(selector).tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', 'test');
```

It works.

The only thing I noticed buy debugging is that `$(selector).tagsinput('input').typeahead` points to a different function outside and inside the event handler function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i write this

```
$("#TagsInput").tagsinput("input").typeahead("val", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. [There](https://github.com/TimSchlechter/bootstrap-tagsinput/blob/master/examples/assets/app_bs3.js#L3-L4) you can see the correct use.

You must set typeahead in second line:

```
$(selector).tagsinput();
$(selector).tagsinput('input').typeahead('setQuery', '');
```